# How to change permissions of a file on Google Drive to share it with anyone with link as viewer?

Tags: c#, .net, database, google-drive-api

I tried many things but I can't get it working:

```
Permission permission = new Permission ( );
permission.Role = "reader";
permission.Type = "anyone";
permission.Id = "anyoneWithLink";

service.Permissions.Delete ( file.Id, file.PermissionIds [ 0 ] ).Execute();
service.Permissions.Update ( permission, file.Id, permission.Id ).Execute ( );
```

I see 2 permissions for some files, one with an Id set to "anyoneWithLink" but not sure if it's what I set as a user in Google Drive website. Because any other file that I didn't touch in the Google Drive website, their permissions are still owner, default, not anyoneWithLink.

How can I set the permissions for a file properly so the changes go through?

Credentials code:

```
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string [ ] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main ( string [ ] args )
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using ( var stream =
            new FileStream ( "credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) )
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync (
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load ( stream ).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore ( credPath, true ) ).Result;
            Console.WriteLine ( "Credential file saved to: " + credPath );
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService ( new BaseClientService.Initializer ( )
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### After you delete a permission, you cannot update it - you need to [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) a new one.

- When creating a new permission (also when updating one) - do not supply a `permissionId` in the request body
- Instead, just provide as resource

```c#
Permission permission = new Permission ( );
permission.Role = "reader";
permission.Type = "anyone";
```

- Setting `permission.Type` to `anyone` is enough for the file to become accessible by `anyoneWithLink`.

Note:

After setting the permissions correctly, from the UI it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but after you create it, which function do you use to update it on the file? Update or some other function?

Comment: I tried service.Permissions.Create ( permission, file.Id ), but after I process all files, the new files I didn't touch in the Google Drive website, they don't get the new permissions. I also tried calling execute on this but that one fails with 403. So not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You create the new permission with `Permissions.Create(permission, file.Id).Execute();` as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1PermissionsResource.html#af6b84f89066d04f233b51aac146150d3). If this gives you a 403 error it either means that the file is located on a shared drive or that the file is not yours but e.g. has been shared with you by a link (this would explain why you can carry out the request after opening the file from the UI. Can you verify this?

Comment: Hi, it's my own Google Drive, I own all the files. In the UI, if I share it, I see it restricted by default, but not sure how else I can verify this?

Comment: And I am listed with my email as the owner.

Comment: Can you test tith the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create?)? With the request body `{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "anyone"
}`.

Comment: Ok I got it working, it returns 200: {
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "id": "anyoneWithLink",
 "type": "anyone",
 "role": "reader",
 "allowFileDiscovery": false
}

Comment: No I still get the same error immediately. Maybe my credentials is wrong? I tried Drive also instead of DriveReadOnly, same result. I posted the code on the question.

Comment: You need the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.After you changed the scopes, did you delete the `token.json` file to reset the euhtnetication flow?

Comment: Thanks before you told me, I did that exactly and it did work now. So hard to figure it out. Btw when I add the new permissions, it keeps the old one, i.e. owner, me? Is that normal?

Comment: If you give reader permissions (or editor permissions) to anyone with the link, you will still be the owner of the file, but from the UI you can see `Anyone on the internet with this link can view` - see screenshot. Providing access with link to anyone will not change the already existing permissions - you need to delete them if desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes sense. Now I am able to get the shared links in order so I can save them to a file, something Google Drive doesn't do unfortunately.